# Rails nested form redirect issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect, nested

I'm creating app with a sign up process as follows:

1. User signs their company up (parent account) and creates their
   user account (child account) in the same form.
2. User logs in and adds other child accounts for other employees.

Each company account acts as a "wrapper" to connect all of the user accounts.

I've got this working, but can't seem to get the code to redirect back to the root url of the app after the user submits the form. currently, they are being forwarded to the companies index.

Thanks!

**My two models:**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :users_attributes

  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :created_on, :company_id

  belongs_to :company
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tasks

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

end
```

**Company Controller**

```
  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.users.build
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(params[:company])

    if @company.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
```

**And the form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@company) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :users do |u| %>
    <%= u.input :first_name %>
    <%= u.input :last_name %>
    <HR>
    <%= u.input :email %>
    <%= u.input :password %>
    <%= u.input :password_confirmation %>
  <% end %>


  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :address1 %>
    <%= f.input :address2 %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :state %>
    <%= f.input :zip %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT:**

My Routes

```
  resources :password_reset

  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "adduser" => "users#new", :as => "adduser"
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  resources :companies
  get "signup" => "companies#new", :as => "signup"

  resources :comments

  root :to => "projects#index"

  resources :tasks do
    member do
      get :change
    end
  end

  resources :phases

  resources :projects
```

Comment: FWIW, I copied your code into a test app and it worked for me (routed me back to projects/index as the root url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect to the '/' path instead of using a route for a quick fix.

**Company Controller**

```
def new
  @company = Company.new
  @company.users.build
end

def create
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])

  if @company.save
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: That did the trick! Still wondering why my routing is messed up, as redirecting to the root_url is working in other areas, but who knows. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is defined in routes.rb ?

Probably you forgot to change it to what you whant the root_url to be

Comment: root :to => "projects#index"

Comment: could you post all your routes ?